# BCM 2007 not opening contacts

Tags: outlook-2007

Business Contact Manager for Outlook (2007) is refusing to open contacts. This problem appeared this morning on every machine (Windows XP SP3) on our network.

The contact list does populate as normal, and contacts can be printed from the context menu, but the form that displays the contact information does not display, and no error message is thrown. I have turned on logging for BCM in the help menu, but nothing is being generated (or, leastways, I cannot find it anywhere).

The SQL services appear to have started as normal.

Anyone come across this before I take a deep breath and go with my boss' suggestion of "just reboot the server"?

Any other information you need?

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem. It looks like it is something to do with BCM forms not loading anymore. My workaround was to go into Business Contact Manager menu in Outlook, then Customize Forms, then Manage User-Defined Fields then click Business Contacts.

Select any group you see on the left hand column and click the >> button to move it to the right. Click OK; now you should be able to open your contact. If it works, go back to the User-defined fields and move the group back to the left.

This will reinitialize the form, getting rid of whatever corruption prevented it loading.